# Root permission problems with Ansible although logged in as root

Tags: permissions, installation, root, ansible

I am trying to automate a simple package installation routine:

1. copy package files to remote (Solaris) host
2. log in as `root`
3. execute `pkgadd <pkg_name>`

This works very well when doing it manually, however Ansible fails during the `pkgadd` step with an "ERROR: The database may only be accessed as root" that never happens when doing exactly the same procedure manually:

```
---
- name: deploy JRE
  synchronize: src={{jre_path}} dest={{remote_pkg_repo}}

- name: install JRE
  command: pkgadd {{jre_name}}  chdir={{remote_pkg_repo}}
```

I'm certain that Ansible is using the root user, a simple debug statement showed me that it is logged in as `uid=0(root) gid=0(root)`, but still that error occurs. What's going on here?

PS: there is no `sudo` installed on the remote machine that could be used.

**update**

I can reproduce the error when performing the `pkgadd` command using a remote SSH command:

```
ssh root@<remote_host> 'cd <remote_pkg_repo>; pkgadd <pkg_name>'
```

What is the difference between this remote SSH call and a manual login?

Comment: add `-vvvv` to your run of Ansible, paste the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the above problem. Since Ansible logs into the remote host via SSH, only a "remote shell" is created (which seems lack some environment configuration compared to a manual login).

So in order to make Ansible remotely log in as `root` and execute a command with full `root` priviledges, you must set the environment variable `NONABI_SCRIPTS=true` in your Ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: <your_host>
  remote_user: root

  vars:
  # set the environment in a task to avoid a remote shell
  # but enforce a real local shell:
    enforce_local_shell:
      NONABI_SCRIPTS: true
```

Then add an `environment` to your Ansible task:

```
- name: install JRE
  command: pkgadd {{jre_name}}  chdir={{remote_pkg_repo}}
  environment: enforce_local_shell
```

More information about setting up your Ansible environment can be found [here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_environment.html).